# How to add an additonal uvm_reg write to each register map access?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am looking for a way to add always an additional uvm_reg write access when I read or write to an uvm_reg. The flow is shown in the pseudo code.

pseudo code:

```
reg_map.MY_REGS.REG1.write( status, <my data >);
```

This should always be :

```
reg_map.MY_CTRL_REG.CFG   ( status, <data> );
reg_map.MY_REGS.REG1.write( status, <data> );
```

Idea was to use alternative frontdoor access get the address from the rw_info and add the additional write, but this fails because this is a recursive call.

Is there a way to customize the reg_map read,write and update command and add a to the original access a private uvm_reg write ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UVM register callbacks class - `uvm_reg_cbs`. 
https://www.vmmcentral.com/uvm_vmm_ik/files3/reg/uvm_reg_cbs-svh.html

1) Extend this class and populate your pre_write virtual function

2) Register your call back class with the reg_block you wish to use it with. (Look at uvm_callback::add)

https://www.vmmcentral.com/uvm_vmm_ik/files3/base/uvm_callback-svh.html#uvm_callback

Good luck!